# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(k-z)^2}{(k-w)^3}}$ with $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to determine the values of $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(k-z)^2}{(k-w)^3}}
$$
converges, converges absolutely and diverges. Of course, an immediate necessary condition for the convergence  is $w \notin \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, if $z,w \in \mathbb{R}$ is more or less clear since in that case we can apply the integral test: we have that the indefinite integral is given by
$$
\int_{}^{}{\frac{(x-z)^2}{(x-w)^3}}dx=\log(x-w)-\frac{(z-w)(z+3w-4x)}{2(w-x)^2}
$$
Therefore, if $N$ is an integer such that $N>w$ and we integrate on the interval $[N,\infty]$ we get that the corresponding improper integral diverges and thus the series also diverges. Now, if $z$ and $w$ are arbitrary complex numbers I am not sure how to proceed. At the outset I thought it would be useful to use the fact that a sequence $(z_n) \subset \mathbb{C}$ converges if and only if $({\rm Re}(z_n))$ and $({\rm Im}(z_n))$ both converge because in that way we could return to the real case again. However the real and imaginary parts of the term $\frac{(k-z)^2}{(k-w)^3}$ is more complicated than I expected. Then, I tried to use the ratio test and to root test, however as you can imagine that didn't improve the situation haha.

Any suggestion?

In advance thank you very much.

**Edit: As you can see, so far the "conjecture" is that the series diverges for all $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$ but of course I'd like to come up with a proof.**

Comment: Seems like none of them. This can be written as: $$\sum\frac1k\frac{(1-z/k)^2}{(1-w/k)^3}$$ and the second part is bounded away from $0$ for large $k.$

Comment: In particular, for large $k$ the real part of $\frac{(1-z/k)^2}{(1-w/k)^3}$ is greater than $\frac12,$ and thus the real part of your sum is bounded below by $\sum\frac1{2k},$ which diverges.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews hmmmmm interesting, let me convince myself  (sometimes I am a little bit slow haha) :). Thank you very much for your help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct.

This can be written as: $$\sum\frac1k\frac{(1-z/k)^2}{(1-w/k)^3}$$ and the second part is bounded away from $0$ for large $k.$

Specifically, since $c_k=\frac{(1-z/k)^2}{(1-w/k)^3}\to1$ as $k\to \infty,$ we know that there is a $K$ such that for all $k>K,$ $\operatorname{Re}(c_k)>\frac12.$ So for $k>K,$ the real part of your term is bigger than $\frac1{2k},$ and hence cannot converge, since $\sum\frac1{2k}$ does not converge.

---

Really, this would work for any pair of functions $f(k),g(k)$ such that $\frac{kf(k)}{g(k)}$ converges to any non-zero value. Then:

$$\sum \frac{f(k)}{g(k)}$$ diverges.

Comment: Oh you're right! Pfff I definitely didn't thinks in this approach. Well, thanks to you I have learned something new :). Thanks for your help!